# Как выполнить считывание картинки и doc-документа в PyQt5 и вывести в двоичном коде?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

Делал дизайн в *Qt Designer*

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
# - import model
# + from model import Ui_model
class Ui_model(object):
    def setupUi(self, model):
        model.setObjectName("model")
        model.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        model.resize(907, 656)
        model.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(187, 211, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(model)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 390, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Papyrus")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 410, 871, 20))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 380, 871, 20))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 580, 881, 21))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 490, 221, 61))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 170, 0);\n"
                                        "font: 87 10pt \"Arial Black\";\n"
                                        "")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
                                        "font: 87 10pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.widget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 430, 481, 121))
        self.widget1.setObjectName("widget1")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget1)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_16, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_14, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_15, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_9, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_12, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_9, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_13, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_8, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6, 3, 3, 1, 1)
        self.widget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 70, 221, 161))
        self.widget2.setObjectName("widget2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget2)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(214, 193, 255);\n"
                                        "font: 75 15pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget2)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(214, 193, 255);\n"
                                      "font: 75 15pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
                                      "")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.widget3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 430, 382, 48))
        self.widget3.setObjectName("widget3")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget3)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget3)
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_17, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget3)
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_11, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget3)
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_18, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget3)
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_10, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.widget4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 260, 211, 65))
        self.widget4.setObjectName("widget4")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget4)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.widget4)
        self.checkBox.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 3, 15);")
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.widget4)
        self.checkBox_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.checkBox_2)
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.widget4)
        self.checkBox_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName("checkBox_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.checkBox_3)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(411, 11, 154, 38))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Papyrus")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.widget5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(412, 67, 251, 201))
        self.widget5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(251, 201))
        self.widget5.setObjectName("widget5")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget5)
        self.gridLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget5)
        self.spinBox.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(89, 18))
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(10)
        self.spinBox.setSingleStep(1)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.spinBox, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.label_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(154, 18))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.spinBox_3 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget5)
        self.spinBox_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(89, 18))
        self.spinBox_3.setMaximum(150)
        self.spinBox_3.setObjectName("spinBox_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.spinBox_3, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_5, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.spinBox_2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget5)
        self.spinBox_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(89, 18))
        self.spinBox_2.setMaximum(1000)
        self.spinBox_2.setObjectName("spinBox_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.spinBox_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_6, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.spinBox_4 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget5)
        self.spinBox_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(89, 18))
        self.spinBox_4.setMaximum(5000)
        self.spinBox_4.setObjectName("spinBox_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.spinBox_4, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_7, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.spinBox_5 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget5)
        self.spinBox_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(89, 18))
        self.spinBox_5.setMaximum(1024)
        self.spinBox_5.setObjectName("spinBox_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.spinBox_5, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_8, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.spinBox_8 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget5)
        self.spinBox_8.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(89, 18))
        self.spinBox_8.setMaximum(20)
        self.spinBox_8.setObjectName("spinBox_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.spinBox_8, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.widget6 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 280, 177, 58))
        self.widget6.setObjectName("widget6")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget6)
        self.gridLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget6)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(214, 193, 255);\n"
                                        "font: 75 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget6)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(214, 193, 255);\n"
                                        "font: 75 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.gridLayout_4.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3, 0, 1, 2, 1)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget6)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_11, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget6)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_10, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        model.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(model)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        model.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.action_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action_2.setObjectName("action_2")
        self.action_3 = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action_3.setObjectName("action_3")
        self.action_5 = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action_5.setObjectName("action_5")
        self.action_6 = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action_6.setObjectName("action_6")
        self.action_7 = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action_7.setObjectName("action_7")

        self.retranslateUi(model)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(model)

    def retranslateUi(self, model):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        model.setWindowTitle(_translate("model", "Модель цифровых систем передачи с решающей обратной связью"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("model", "Результат испытания"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("model", "START"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("model", "STOP"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("model", "Принято"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("model", "Ошибки"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("model", "Коэффициент ошибки"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("model", "Биты"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("model", "Байты"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("model", "Блоки"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("model", "РОС - АП"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("model", "РОС - ОЖ"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("model", "Скорость передачи полезной информации, Бод"))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("model", "Количество повторений искажённых блоков"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("model", "Моделирование в реальном времени"))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("model", "Моделировать аварию"))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("model", "Анимация передачи"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("model", "Параметры испытания"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("model", "Уровень шума, В"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("model", "Частота шума, Кгц"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("model", "Уровень полезного сигнала, В"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("model", "Скорость передачи, Бод"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("model", "Размер блока, байт"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("model", "Повторы искажённых блоков"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("model", "ИС"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("model", "ПС"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("model", "Приёмник сигнала"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("model", "Источник сигнала"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("model", "Сохранить"))
        self.action_2.setText(_translate("model", "Открыть"))
        self.action_3.setText(_translate("model", "Выйти"))
        self.action_5.setText(_translate("model", "Выйти из программы"))
        self.action_6.setText(_translate("model", "Выбрать источник сигнала"))
        self.action_7.setText(_translate("model", "Выбрать приёмник сигнала"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_model):
    def __init__(self):
        # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
        # и т.д. в файле design.py
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.data = None
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_IS)

    def on_clicked_IS(self):
        fname, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Open File', './', 'Files (*.html *.txt *.log)'
        )
        if fname:
            with open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
                self.data = fh.readlines()
                print(*self.data, sep='')



def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Как добавить в этот кусок:

```
def on_clicked_IS(self):
        fname, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Open File', './', 'Files (*.html *.txt *.log)'
        )
        if fname:
            with open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
                self.data = fh.readlines()
                print(*self.data, sep='')
```

Чтобы программа считывала файл картинку (`*.png / *jpg`) и выводила его в двоичном коде?

И для  `*.doc` тоже самое.

Answer (score 0):

Читать можно по-разному, но я не знаю, что вы с ним будете делать дальше.
Вот вам некоторые варианты.

```
import sys
import cv2
from docx import Document
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#- import model
#+ from model import Ui_model
class Ui_model(object):
    def setupUi(self, model):
        model.setObjectName("model")
        model.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        model.resize(907, 656)
        model.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(187, 211, 255);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(model)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 390, 161, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Papyrus")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 410, 871, 20))
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.line_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 380, 871, 20))
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.progressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.centralwidget)
        self.progressBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 580, 881, 21))
        self.progressBar.setProperty("value", 24)
        self.progressBar.setObjectName("progressBar")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(550, 490, 221, 61))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 170, 0);\n"
"font: 87 10pt \"Arial Black\";\n"
"")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"font: 87 10pt \"Arial Black\";")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.widget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 430, 481, 121))
        self.widget1.setObjectName("widget1")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget1)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label_16 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_16.setObjectName("label_16")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_16, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_14.setObjectName("label_14")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_14, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.label_15 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_15.setObjectName("label_15")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_15, 0, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_9, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_4, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_7 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_7.setObjectName("lineEdit_7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_7, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_12.setObjectName("label_12")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_12, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_9 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_9.setObjectName("lineEdit_9")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_9, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 2, 2, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 2, 3, 1, 1)
        self.label_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget1)
        self.label_13.setObjectName("label_13")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_13, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_8 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_8.setObjectName("lineEdit_8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_8, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_5, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_6 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget1)
        self.lineEdit_6.setObjectName("lineEdit_6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_6, 3, 3, 1, 1)
        self.widget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 70, 221, 161))
        self.widget2.setObjectName("widget2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget2)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(214, 193, 255);\n"
"font: 75 15pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget2)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(214, 193, 255);\n"
"font: 75 15pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.widget3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 430, 382, 48))
        self.widget3.setObjectName("widget3")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget3)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.label_17 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget3)
        self.label_17.setObjectName("label_17")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_17, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_11 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget3)
        self.lineEdit_11.setObjectName("lineEdit_11")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_11, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_18 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget3)
        self.label_18.setObjectName("label_18")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_18, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_10 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget3)
        self.lineEdit_10.setObjectName("lineEdit_10")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.lineEdit_10, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.widget4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 260, 211, 65))
        self.widget4.setObjectName("widget4")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget4)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.widget4)
        self.checkBox.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 3, 15);")
        self.checkBox.setObjectName("checkBox")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.checkBox)
        self.checkBox_2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.widget4)
        self.checkBox_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.checkBox_2.setObjectName("checkBox_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.checkBox_2)
        self.checkBox_3 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self.widget4)
        self.checkBox_3.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);")
        self.checkBox_3.setObjectName("checkBox_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.checkBox_3)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(411, 11, 154, 38))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Papyrus")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.widget5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(412, 67, 251, 201))
        self.widget5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(251, 201))
        self.widget5.setObjectName("widget5")
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget5)
        self.gridLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget5)
        self.spinBox.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(89, 18))
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(10)
        self.spinBox.setSingleStep(1)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.spinBox, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.label_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(154, 18))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.spinBox_3 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget5)
        self.spinBox_3.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(89, 18))
        self.spinBox_3.setMaximum(150)
        self.spinBox_3.setObjectName("spinBox_3")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.spinBox_3, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_5, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.spinBox_2 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget5)
        self.spinBox_2.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(89, 18))
        self.spinBox_2.setMaximum(1000)
        self.spinBox_2.setObjectName("spinBox_2")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.spinBox_2, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_6, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.spinBox_4 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget5)
        self.spinBox_4.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(89, 18))
        self.spinBox_4.setMaximum(5000)
        self.spinBox_4.setObjectName("spinBox_4")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.spinBox_4, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_7, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.spinBox_5 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget5)
        self.spinBox_5.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(89, 18))
        self.spinBox_5.setMaximum(1024)
        self.spinBox_5.setObjectName("spinBox_5")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.spinBox_5, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_8, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.spinBox_8 = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget5)
        self.spinBox_8.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(89, 18))
        self.spinBox_8.setMaximum(20)
        self.spinBox_8.setObjectName("spinBox_8")
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.spinBox_8, 5, 1, 1, 1)
        self.widget6 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 280, 177, 58))
        self.widget6.setObjectName("widget6")
        self.gridLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.widget6)
        self.gridLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_4.setObjectName("gridLayout_4")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget6)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(214, 193, 255);\n"
"font: 75 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget6)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(214, 193, 255);\n"
"font: 75 10pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.pushButton_6)
        self.gridLayout_4.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_3, 0, 1, 2, 1)
        self.label_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget6)
        self.label_11.setObjectName("label_11")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_11, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget6)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.gridLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_10, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        model.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(model)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        model.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action.setObjectName("action")
        self.action_2 = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action_2.setObjectName("action_2")
        self.action_3 = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action_3.setObjectName("action_3")
        self.action_5 = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action_5.setObjectName("action_5")
        self.action_6 = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action_6.setObjectName("action_6")
        self.action_7 = QtWidgets.QAction(model)
        self.action_7.setObjectName("action_7")

        self.retranslateUi(model)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(model)

    def retranslateUi(self, model):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        model.setWindowTitle(_translate("model", "Модель цифровых систем передачи с решающей обратной связью"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("model", "Результат испытания"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("model", "START"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("model", "STOP"))
        self.label_16.setText(_translate("model", "Принято"))
        self.label_14.setText(_translate("model", "Ошибки"))
        self.label_15.setText(_translate("model", "Коэффициент ошибки"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("model", "Биты"))
        self.label_12.setText(_translate("model", "Байты"))
        self.label_13.setText(_translate("model", "Блоки"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("model", "РОС - АП"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("model", "РОС - ОЖ"))
        self.label_17.setText(_translate("model", "Скорость передачи полезной информации, Бод"))
        self.label_18.setText(_translate("model", "Количество повторений искажённых блоков"))
        self.checkBox.setText(_translate("model", "Моделирование в реальном времени"))
        self.checkBox_2.setText(_translate("model", "Моделировать аварию"))
        self.checkBox_3.setText(_translate("model", "Анимация передачи"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("model", "Параметры испытания"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("model", "Уровень шума, В"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("model", "Частота шума, Кгц"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("model", "Уровень полезного сигнала, В"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("model", "Скорость передачи, Бод"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("model", "Размер блока, байт"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("model", "Повторы искажённых блоков"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("model", "ИС"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("model", "ПС"))
        self.label_11.setText(_translate("model", "Приёмник сигнала"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("model", "Источник сигнала"))
        self.action.setText(_translate("model", "Сохранить"))
        self.action_2.setText(_translate("model", "Открыть"))
        self.action_3.setText(_translate("model", "Выйти"))
        self.action_5.setText(_translate("model", "Выйти из программы"))
        self.action_6.setText(_translate("model", "Выбрать источник сигнала"))
        self.action_7.setText(_translate("model", "Выбрать приёмник сигнала"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_model):
    def __init__(self):
# ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????
        # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
        # и т.д. в файле design.py
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.data = None
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked_IS)
        
    def on_clicked_IS(self):
        fname, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Open File', './'                               #, 'Files (*.html *.txt *.log)'
        )
        if fname:
            print()
            if fname.endswith("docx") or fname.endswith("doc"):
                print("doc / docx")
                with open(fname, 'rb') as fh:
                    self.data = fh.read()
                    print(type(self.data))
                    print(self.data[:20])  
                    
                    document = Document(fh)
                    print(type(document))
                    print(document)                    
                
            elif fname.endswith("png") or fname.endswith("jpg"):
                print("png / jpg")
                img = cv2.imread(fname, 0)
                print(type(img))
                print(img[:20])
                # или
                with open(fname, 'rb') as fh:
                    self.data = fh.read()
                    print(type(self.data))
                    print(self.data[:20])
                
            elif fname.endswith("txt") or fname.endswith("log"):
                print("txt / log")
                with open(fname, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as fh:
                    self.data = fh.readlines()
                    print(* self.data, sep='')
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возникли проблемы с 1)ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' . 2)from docx import Document

Comment: @Rintys закомментируйте пока эти строки и и строки где есть `cv2` и `document`

Comment: Сделал, для doc вот это показывает сейчас: doc / docx
<class 'bytes'>
b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00\xdf\xa4\xd2lZ\x01'

Comment: @Rintys да, а вы что хотели увидеть ?

Comment: а, всё окей с доком, а по поводу картинки, он выводит только png / jpg, И в байты как у вас на картинки не считывает, это из-за импорта этого долбанного cv2, которого не получается импортировать, через cmd загрузил, а всё равно ошибку выдаёт

Comment: @Rintys `он выводит только png / jpg` потому что  `fname.endswith("png") or fname.endswith("jpg")`. Уберите строки где есть `cv2` или `img`.

Comment: Поубирал, всё равно в таком виде b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00\xdf\xa что док что картинки, а нужно именно в двоичном формате , 0 и 1

Comment: @Rintys   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815592/convert-bytes-to-bits-in-python The End.